# Unable to build sqlcipher3 on Windows

Tags: python, c, sqlite, sqlcipher

after building sqlcipher, copied sqlite3.c and sqlite3.h in the root folder, I'm trying to build [sqlcipher3](https://github.com/coleifer/sqlcipher3) (on Windows 10, Python 3.9.0):

```
C:\dev\py\sqlcipher3# setup.py build_static build
running build_static
Builds a C extension using a sqlcipher amalgamation
building 'sqlcipher3._sqlite3' extension
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29333\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -DMODULE_NAME="sqlcipher3.dbapi2" -DSQLITE_ENABLE_FTS3=1 -DSQLITE_ENABLE_FTS3_PARENTHESIS=1 -DSQLITE_ENABLE_FTS4=1 -DSQLITE_ENABLE_FTS5=1 -DSQLITE_ENABLE_JSON1=1 -DSQLITE_ENABLE_LOAD_EXTENSION=1 -DSQLITE_ENABLE_RTREE=1 -DSQLITE_ENABLE_STAT4=1 -DSQLITE_ENABLE_UPDATE_DELETE_LIMIT=1 -DSQLITE_HAS_CODEC=1 -DSQLITE_SOUNDEX=1 -DSQLITE_USE_URI=1 -DSQLITE_TEMP_STORE=2 -DSQLITE_MAX_VARIABLE_NUMBER=250000 -DSQLITE_DEFAULT_PAGE_SIZE=4096 -DSQLITE_DEFAULT_CACHE_SIZE=-8000 -Dinline=__inline -I. -IC:\OpenSSL-Win64\include -IC:\Python\include -IC:\Python\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29333\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.8\include\um -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\shared -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\winrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\cppwinrt /Tc.\sqlite3.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release.\sqlite3.obj
sqlite3.c
.\sqlite3.c(24335): warning C4996: 'fopen': This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using fopen_s instead. To disable deprecation, use _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. See online help for details.
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29333\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -DMODULE_NAME="sqlcipher3.dbapi2" -DSQLITE_ENABLE_FTS3=1 -DSQLITE_ENABLE_FTS3_PARENTHESIS=1 -DSQLITE_ENABLE_FTS4=1 -DSQLITE_ENABLE_FTS5=1 -DSQLITE_ENABLE_JSON1=1 -DSQLITE_ENABLE_LOAD_EXTENSION=1 -DSQLITE_ENABLE_RTREE=1 -DSQLITE_ENABLE_STAT4=1 -DSQLITE_ENABLE_UPDATE_DELETE_LIMIT=1 -DSQLITE_HAS_CODEC=1 -DSQLITE_SOUNDEX=1 -DSQLITE_USE_URI=1 -DSQLITE_TEMP_STORE=2 -DSQLITE_MAX_VARIABLE_NUMBER=250000 -DSQLITE_DEFAULT_PAGE_SIZE=4096 -DSQLITE_DEFAULT_CACHE_SIZE=-8000 -Dinline=__inline -I. -IC:\OpenSSL-Win64\include -IC:\Python\include -IC:\Python\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29333\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.8\include\um -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\shared -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\winrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\cppwinrt /Tcsrc\blob.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release\src\blob.obj
blob.c
src\blob.c(178): warning C4244: 'function': conversion from 'Py_ssize_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
src\blob.c(359): warning C4244: 'function': conversion from 'Py_ssize_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
src\blob.c(386): warning C4244: 'function': conversion from 'Py_ssize_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
src\blob.c(408): warning C4244: 'function': conversion from 'Py_ssize_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
src\blob.c(421): warning C4244: 'function': conversion from 'Py_ssize_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
src\blob.c(421): warning C4244: 'function': conversion from 'Py_ssize_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
src\blob.c(439): warning C4244: 'function': conversion from 'Py_ssize_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
src\blob.c(439): warning C4244: 'function': conversion from 'Py_ssize_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
src\blob.c(508): warning C4244: 'function': conversion from 'Py_ssize_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
src\blob.c(536): warning C4244: 'function': conversion from 'Py_ssize_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
src\blob.c(550): warning C4244: 'function': conversion from 'Py_ssize_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
src\blob.c(550): warning C4244: 'function': conversion from 'Py_ssize_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
src\blob.c(574): warning C4244: 'function': conversion from 'Py_ssize_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
src\blob.c(574): warning C4244: 'function': conversion from 'Py_ssize_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
src\blob.c(638): error C2017: illegal escape sequence
src\blob.c(638): error C2224: left of '.Blob' must have struct/union type
src\blob.c(638): error C2001: newline in constant
src\blob.c(638): error C2059: syntax error: 'string'
error: command 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29333\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2
```

Here the lines in Blob.c (line 638 is `MODULE_NAME ".Blob",`):

```
PyTypeObject pysqlite_BlobType = {
        PyVarObject_HEAD_INIT(NULL, 0)
        MODULE_NAME ".Blob",
        .tp_basicsize = sizeof(pysqlite_Blob),
        .tp_dealloc = (destructor)pysqlite_blob_dealloc,
        .tp_as_sequence = &blob_sequence_methods,
        .tp_as_mapping = &blob_mapping_methods,
        .tp_flags = Py_TPFLAGS_DEFAULT,
        .tp_weaklistoffset = offsetof(pysqlite_Blob, in_weakreflist),
        .tp_methods = blob_methods,
};
```

Can someone help me to proceed?
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just had the same issue today, with pretty much exactly the same setup. I needed to do two modifications in order to successfully compile sqlcipher3:

1. The content of the `MODULE_NAME` precompiler definition is set in line 38 of `setup.py`. The function `quote_argument`, which is called here, differentiates between Windows and other platforms. On Windows, the quote character is escaped with a backslash. At least for MSVC2019, this seems to be incorrect. To fix it, just remove the Windows-specific stuff on line 35.
2. The library names of OpenSSL have changed in version 1.1.0. If you are using a newer version, you might have to change the library name from `libeay32.lib` to `libcrypto.lib` or whatever the library is called on your system (in line 132). In addition, you might have to set the environment variable `OPENSSL_CONF`, to help the build script to find OpenSSL on your system.

With these two small modifications, the build process worked fine.

Comment: I am glad I could help!